# Let $G(x)=F(x^2)$ so find $G'(x)$ without using chain rule

Tags: calculus

Im a little confused on it I had some tricks arriving in :

G'(x)=$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{G(x+h)-G(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(\,(x+h)^2)-F(x^2)}{h}$
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(\,(x+h)^2)-F(x^2)}{h}.\frac{(x+h)^2-(x)^2}{(x+h)^2-(x)^2}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(\,(x+h)^2)-F(x^2)}{(x+h)^2-(x)^2}.\frac{(x+h)^2-(x)^2}{h}$

So the second term it's $2x$, what is good since we have to arriven in $2x.F'(x^2)$, so the first term must be $F'(x^2)$ but doing $F'(x^2)$ separately I've gotten$\lim\limits_{0} {QFx^2}$=$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x^2+h)-F(x^2)}{h}$
So i just need to prove that
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x^2+h)-F(x^2)}{h}$=$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(\,(x+h)^2)-F(x^2)}{h}$

Help

Comment: That is not correct. You cannot find $\frac{dF(x^2)}{dx}$ by using $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F(x^2+h)-F(x^2)}{h}=\frac{dF(x^2)}{d(x^2)}$.

Comment: So how i calculate$ F'(a^2)$?

Comment: You already have. The form that is written is the correct way to evaluate it.

Comment: so what is the limit form of it?

Comment: $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{(x+h)-x}\implies \frac{dF(x^2)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F((x+h)^2)-F(x^2)}{(x+h)^2-x^2}$. All of the domain values are squared.

Comment: So I want to calculate the derivative of 3, i use the fisrt, and if i want to calculate the derivative of 9 i use the second? $x$ for me represents some point in general elevated to square, Spivak says this here  https://prnt.sc/nddflr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92584/discussion-between-peter-foreman-and-jordan).